# Likelihood function in terms of latent variable

Tags: probability, distributions, likelihood, latent-variable

Suppose that $\underline{Y}$ are observed counts and a latent variable $\underline{Z}$ follows a discrete distribution with parameters $\theta$. Also, the $\underline{Y}$ is a linear transformation of $\underline{Z}$, i.e $\underline{Y}=f(\underline{Z})$ where $f$ is non invertible. In my notes it says that we can write the likelihood in the following form:

$L(\theta|\underline{Y}) = \sum_{\underline{Z}:\underline{Y}=f(\underline{Z})}P(\underline{Z}=\underline{z}|\theta)$

But why is that true? We want to express the likelihood in terms of the data, i.e $\underline{Y}$ but we end up with a sum of latent variables $\underline{Z}$.

Comment: How is f non-invertible and does represent a linear transformation? Also, can the summation be over log-probs?

Comment: @gunes  we might have that $Y=AZ$, where $A$ is a matrix that is not invertible, but $Y$ is still a linear transformation of $Z$

Comment: @Xi'an I thought about that because $Z$ is latent, but we shouldn't have somewhere a product for $Y$??

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of it as a random vector.

Comment: @gunes I'll change the notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This representation is a marginalisation of the joint distribution of $Z$ and $Y$, with $$\mathbb P_\theta(Z=z,Y=y)=\mathbb P_\theta(Z=z)\mathbb I_{y=f(z)}$$since $Y$ is a deterministic transform of $Z$. Therefore
$$\mathbb P_\theta(Y=y)=\sum_z \mathbb P_\theta(Z=z,Y=y)=\sum_z \mathbb P_\theta(Z=z)\mathbb I_{y=f(z)}=\sum_{z; f(z)=y} \mathbb P_\theta(Z=z)$$

Comment: $Y$ is a vector if we had assumed independence between the elements of the vector, then we would have $\prod_{i}\sum_{z}\mathbb{P}_{\theta}(Z=z, Y=y_{i})=\prod_{i}\sum_{z}\mathbb{P}(Z=z)\mathbb{I}_{y_{i}=f(z)}$, where for $y_{i}=f(z)$ it is possible to corresdpon to $y_{i}$ equal to the multiplication of the $ith$ row of a matrix with the vector $z$?